# jquery remote validation username check

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

I have been looking around and i still cannot figure out why my username validation is not working. I am just to check if the username exists and if it does show an error message. Here is the rules for my username field.

```
username:
        {
            required: true,
            remote: "user-check.php"
        },
```

Here is the message part.

```
username:
        {
            required: 'Please enter a username',
            remote: 'Username is taken'
        },
```

My user-check.php file looks like this.

```
if(isset($_GET['username']) {
$user = $_GET['username'];

$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client_username = ?');

$query->bindValue(1, $user);

$query->execute();

$usercheck = $query->rowCount();

if($usercheck < 1) {
    $valid = "false"; //    <---yes, Validate is expecting a string
} else {
    $valid = "true"; //    <---yes, Validate is expecting a string
}
echo json_encode($valid);
```

}

Any feed back would be awesome driving me crazy. P.S. I am new to posting on here sorry for format.

FIXED and Working.
All errors seemed to come from user-check.php
Here is the fixed version.

```
header('Content-type: application/json');


$user = $_REQUEST['username'];

$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client_username = ?');

$query->bindValue(1, $user);

$query->execute();

$usercheck = $query->rowCount();

if($usercheck == 0) {
    $valid = 'true';
} else {
    $valid = 'false'; 
}
echo $valid;
```

Comment: can you share some more jQuery which you are using?

Comment: hi, why you reply with json_encode($valid); just try this echo $valid;

Comment: You need to return `true` when the username does not exist, not `false`. In the jQuery Validate plugin, `true` represents "passed" validation and `false` represents "failed".  Notice how your new code correctky flips the boolean logic?  Please post your solution below in the answers section, not within your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Notice your original code:**

```
if($usercheck < 1) {   // <-- if no database match
    $valid = "false";  // <-- false => "failed" validation
} else {
    $valid = "true";
}
```

You are returning `false` when there is no match in the database.  This is simply backwards.  If there's no match, you must return `true`, which indicates the field "passed" validation.

**Now notice how the logic is reversed in your "fixed" version:**

```
if($usercheck == 0) {   // <-- if no database match
    $valid = 'true';    // <-- true => "passed" validation
} else {
    $valid = 'false'; 
}
```

[As per jQuery Validate "remote method" documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/):

> The **response is evaluated as JSON** and **must be `true` for valid elements**, and can be any `false`, `undefined` or `null` for invalid elements, using the default message; or a string, eg. "That name is already taken, try peter123 instead" to display as the error message.